# Entity Framework one-to-one with a class that is sometimes independent

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, one-to-one

I have a parent class `ComponentDesign`:

```
public class ComponentDesign
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual JobFile DesignFile { get; set; }
    public int? DesignFileId { get; set; }

    public Pdf PdfFile { get; set; }
    public int? PdfFileId { get; set; }

    public JobFile SealedPdfFile { get; set; }
    public int? SealedPdfFileId { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int JobId { get; set; }
}
```

And a child class `JobFile` (of which `Pdf` is a subclass):

```
public class JobFile
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public ComponentDesign ComponentDesign { get; set; }
    public int? ComponentDesignId { get; set; }

    public int? JobId { get; set; }
}
```

These classes are stored in a relational database using Entity Framework. I would like to have navigation properties on both sides of the relationship, so that I can say `componentDesign.PdfFile` or `jobFile.ComponentDesign` at will.

Each property of type `JobFile` in `ComponentDesign` is optional, and a `JobFile will only ever belong to one`ComponentDesign`. However, a`JobFile`may be free-standing, not belonging to any`ComponentDesign`(so`jobFile.ComponentDesign` would be null).

I'm struggling with how to use the Fluent API to configure this relationship. It is one-to-one. Is it possible to have the navigation properties on both sides of the relationship? Remember that a `JobFile` can be free-standing (so `jobFile.ComponentDesign` will not always be relevant), so there are `JobFile`s that belong to `ComponentDesign`s and ones that don't. The closest I feel I've come is this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ComponentDesign>()
            .HasOptional(componentDesign => componentDesign.DesignFile)
            .WithRequired(jobFile => jobFile.ComponentDesign);
```

But this seems to me to indicate that `jobFile.ComponentDesign` is always required, which isn't the case. I'm hesitant to just try it because it will generate some substantial migrations, so I wanted to get input first. What should my Fluent API configuration look like for this situation?

Comment: To create a relation in Entity Framework between two object classes or let's say datatables you can use the Virtual word with the class type. I am sure you can find results with virtual properties for your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just so that I understand the relationships:

`ComponentDesign` -> `JobFile` = Optional.

`JobFile` -> `ComponentDesign` = Optional.

This is a Zero-or-one to zero-or-one ([0/1]-[0/1]) relationship.

This can be implemented in the following way, using the the `.WithOptionalPrincipal` method in fluent API. With a 1-0 relationship, it's obvious which end is the principal end; same with a 1-∞ relationship. ∞-∞ relationships don't have a principal end, due to the hidden tables created that control the relationships between each. With a 0/1-0/1, or a 1-1 relationship, it's not obvious, and so you must tell the database which end to use as the principal end of the relationship. Among many other things, the pricipal is responsible for initiating, and maintaining the relationship between the tables.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // Configure ComponentDesign & JobFile entity
    modelBuilder.Entity<ComponentDesign>()

        // Mark JobFile property optional in ComponentDesign entity.
        .HasOptional(cd => cd.DesignFile)

        // Mark ComponentDesign property optional in JobFile entity.
        .WithOptionalPrincipal(jf => jf.ComponentDesign); 
}
```

Or, you can create an `EntityTypeConfiguration<>` class for each entity to separate out the relationships, if there are a lot to sort through. While this does decentralise the relationships, it is more scalable, as these configuration classes can be injected via MEF once the context is configured to do so. Just an idea for future development.

If you were configuring the relationship from the JobFile end, you would use `.WithOptionalDependent`, in order to set the navigation correctly, instead of `.WithOptionalPrincipal`. It all depends on which side you configure the relationship from. The `ComponentDesign` entity relies on the `JobFile` entity a lot more than the `JobFile` entity relies on the `ComponentDesign`entity; thus it should be configured as the principal.

As stated in one of the comments above, complex properties should be adorned with the `virtual` keyword. This lazy loads the property, and also, when the class is intansiated, it will set the initial value to be `null`.

Clone the database to a test server, to work on this one problem, then implement the changes on the production model; that way there is no chance of data loss when migrating the database.